# Publish asp.net 5 from visual studio 2015 to linux

Tags: asp.net, linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm figuring out how to publish an asp.net 5 project (from visual studio) so that it works on linux.
In visual studio 2015 I'm using the file system publish function. In settings there is an option for "Target DNX Version". I have 4 options:

- `dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1`
- `dnx-coreclr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1`
- `dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1`
- `dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1`

I installed `dnx-coreclr-linux-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1` with dnvm because I thought that I could use this version to publish in visual studio. After installing it doesn't show up in the list for "Target DNX Version", so I can't publish using the linux dnx.

Am I doing something wrong? dnu, dnx, dnvm is all new to me and it is a bit confusing.

I also know that you can copy the source files and restore/build the project on linux, but a publish of the files seems more 'clean' to me.

Or is this maybe not supported at the moment?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Please note that this only apply to the RC1. The RC2 will not support those executable. They will be replaced by [`dotnet-cli`](https://github.com/dotnet/cli).

I think I know what you want but if it's not exactly that, please let me know and I'll adjust my answer.

### dnvm : .NET Version Manager

Manages the different runtime and allows you also to select the current runtime.

### dnu: .NET Utility

Manages the packages. Mainly used for `dnu restore` once you have your app up and running.

### dnx: .NET Execution Engine

Runs your app/website by executing a command. Normally `dnx web` but `web` is defined in your `project.json` so it can be anything.

### So how do I change my runtime?

So following what we jus saw, if I run `dnvm list` on my system, I get the following:

[image: dnvm list]

Obviously you don't have that. But let's install the `x64` to show an example.

```
dnvm install -a x64 -r clr -version 1.0.0-rc1-final
```

So now I have this:

[image: dnvm list 2]

So I have the 64bits installed but it's not the default runtime and worse... if I restart my command prompt, it will default back to x86. Meaning that everything that runs on this system will automatically default to x86.

Changing the default is just a matter of running this:

```
dnvm alias default -a x64 -r clr -os win -version 1.0.0-rc1-final
dnvm use default -Persistent
```

So now when I restart my command prompt I get:

[image: final dnvm]

This should have you setup and running on the latest runtime. If you are running the process with a different user, I would highly recommend setting that user with the same commands since they are stored in the user `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, that all makes sense. I have the following runtimes installed: http://i.imgur.com/GPUceWJ.png. The problem is actually in Visual Studio. Whenever I want to publish a newly created website in asp.net 5, I don't have the option to select the linux runtime: http://i.imgur.com/EZmuSPB.png. Do you have any idea for this problem? EDIT: maybe the installed runtimes are not related to the visual studio "Target DNX Versions"?

Comment: Everything that you publish as "coreclr" is guaranteed to work on Windows/Linux/OSX. So you don't need to "Publish for Linux". There's no linux Runtime. The only reason the "os" is mentioned in the `dnvm` is just for information purpose. Once your code is started (if coreclr) it will automatically use the active architecture/runtime.

Comment: Or at least those that you mentioned during the publish. I'm not quite 100% up to date on the publishing process yet.

Comment: Aah, that explains! Let me try it when I use the coreclr-win one.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't seem to make any difference if I just use coreclr-win. I should've tried it first of all to see if it was working or not. Thank you for the explanation anyway!

Comment: My pleasure. If my answer matched your question, you can mark it as answered.